# Losing quality after resizing an IMage

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I try to resize images based on the width of the window.
the only problem is that every resize the quality reduce.
Here's my code :

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("1600x900")
root.minsize(200, 200)
root.configure(background="black")

root.columnconfigure(6)
root.rowconfigure(1)


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)


        global root
        self.image = Image.open("img1.png")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img_copy)

        self.label1 = Label(root, image=self.background_image, bd='0')
        self.label1.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.label1.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)
    
        self.label2 = Label(root, image=self.background_image, bd='0')
        self.label2.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="w", padx=5)
        self.label2.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        self.label3 = Label(root, image=self.background_image, bd='0')
        self.label3.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="w")
        self.label3.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        self.label4 = Label(root, image=self.background_image, bd='0')
        self.label4.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky="w", padx=5)
        self.label4.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        self.label5 = Label(root, image=self.background_image, bd='0')
        self.label5.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky="w")
        self.label5.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        self.label6 = Label(root, image=self.background_image, bd='0')
        self.label6.grid(column=6, row=1, sticky="w", padx=5)
        root.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = root.winfo_width()
        new_height = root.winfo_height()

        self.img_copy = self.img_copy.resize((int(new_width / 8),int(new_width / 8 * 3 / 2)))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img_copy)
        self.label1.configure(image =  self.background_image)
        self.label2.configure(image =  self.background_image)
        self.label3.configure(image =  self.background_image)
        self.label4.configure(image =  self.background_image)
        self.label5.configure(image =  self.background_image)
        self.label6.configure(image =  self.background_image)


e = Example(root)
e.place(x=0,y=0)


root.mainloop()
```

There's a video to show what it looks like :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK4zj.jpg

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Resizing ALWAYS reduces the quality.  Are you just saying it's more than you expected?  And what's with the paragraph of gobbledy-gook at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **The reason for the progressing loss in quality is that you don't each time resize from the original image but from the already resized one.**

Change the following part in your code to solve that problem and resize each time from the original image to the new size:

```
def _resize_image(self,event):

    new_width = root.winfo_width()
    new_height = root.winfo_height()

    self.img_resized = self.img_copy.resize((int(new_width / 8),int(new_width / 8 * 3 / 2)))

    self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img_resized)
```

A side effect of resizing a **pixel image** (not vector graphics) is usually loss of image quality of the resized image compared to the original one no matter how good the resizing program and its algorithm is *( check out [a Comparison gallery of image scaling algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_gallery_of_image_scaling_algorithms) )*.

Only enlarging with integer factors like 2x, 3x can preserve the quality of the image. The smaller the resized image compared to the original one the larger is the loss of image quality after enlarging the resized image back to its original size. And yes, also enlarging creates distortions in the image which can't be removed by shrinking the enlarged image back to its original size.

By the way: PIL allows to choose which kind of resizing algorithm should be applied by specifying the parameter resample ( for example: `resample = PIL.Image.LANCZOS` ). If you don't provide this parameter, PIL will choose a default one depending on kind of image to scale.

Below the in question provided, but heavily modified code demonstrating side by side effects of three different approaches to scaling an image:

1. resizing always from the original image
2. resizing from scaled image using a fast, but simple method
3. resizing from scaled image using a sophisticated method (slow)

so you can experience by yourself the impact of the method for resizing an image on image quality and at the same time also experience that tkinter programming can be done without using the overhead of a class for the application:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, filedialog 
from PIL     import Image, ImageTk

def resizeLabels(e=None, new_width=None, new_height=None):
    global padx, mrgx, mrgy, imgPIL_1, imgPIL_2, imgPIL_3
    if new_width is None: 
        new_width  = root.winfo_width()
        # if e is not None: 
        #     assert e.width == root.winfo_width()
    if new_height is None: 
        new_height = root.winfo_height()
        # if e is not None: 
        #     assert e.height == root.winfo_height()

    # Correction of for labels available space size which is less than 
    # the window size due to grid padding and forced margins: 
    new_width  = new_width  - mrgx-3*2*padx
    new_height = new_height - mrgy

    # Resize always from the original image ( no quality loss ): 
    imgPIL_0 = imgPIL_1.resize((int(new_width / 3), int(new_height)))

    # Resize and use resized image for further resizing. Use  two 
    # resize methods: BOX, and LANCZOS (with reducing_gap optimization): 
    imgPIL_2 = imgPIL_2.resize((int(new_width / 3), int(new_height)), 
               resample=Image.BOX)
    imgPIL_3 = imgPIL_3.resize((int(new_width / 3), int(new_height)),
               resample=Image.LANCZOS, reducing_gap = 3.0)

    imgTk_1  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgPIL_0)
    imgTk_2  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgPIL_2)
    imgTk_3  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgPIL_3)

    label_1.config(image=imgTk_1); label_1.image=imgTk_1
    label_2.config(image=imgTk_2); label_2.image=imgTk_2
    label_3.config(image=imgTk_3); label_3.image=imgTk_3
#:def resizeLabels(...)

eventNo = 0
def processConfigureEvent(e):
    global oldWidth, oldHeight, eventNo
    newWidth  = e.width
    newHeight = e.height
    # Reduce the amount of resizing operations by invoking actual resize
    # only if the amount of window size change exceeds given threshold:
    if abs(newWidth+newHeight-oldWidth-oldHeight) > 20:
        eventNo += 1
        print('  eventNo', eventNo, ': ', e, e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height)
        oldWidth  = newWidth
        oldHeight = newHeight
        resizeLabels(e=e)
#:def processConfigureEvent(e)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.title("Scaling To Window Size")
root.geometry("1024x320")
oldWidth = 1024; oldHeight = 320
root.minsize(256, 80)
root.config(background="black")
root.columnconfigure((0,4),   minsize =15) ; mrgx = 30 # root.Grid
root.rowconfigure(   (0,2), {'minsize':15}); mrgy = 30 # root.Grid
padx = 15

file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose an image file',filetypes=[('Image files','*.png *.gif *.jpg *.jpeg'), ('All files', '*.*')])
# file = "img1.png"
imgPIL_1 = Image.open(file)
imgPIL_2 = imgPIL_1.copy()
imgPIL_3 = imgPIL_1.copy()

label_1 = Label(root)
label_1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=15)

label_2 = Label(root)
label_2.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=15)

label_3= Label(root)
label_3.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=15)

# capturing '<Configure>' event occuring on change in root window 
# position or size. Example of printed Configure event object: 
#     <Configure event x=439 y=388 width=1034 height=332>
root.bind('<Configure>', processConfigureEvent)

# initial resizing of labels with not yet active root window requires
# explicit width/height because root.winfo_width/height doesn't yet 
# provide valid root window size values: 
resizeLabels(new_width=oldWidth, new_height=oldHeight)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I needed but i couldn't find the words to ask it properly.